# Show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$ exist

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ differentiable in $[0, 1]$ and $|f'(x)| \leq\frac{1}{2}$ for all $x \in [0, 1]$. If $a_n = f(\frac{1}{n})$, show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$ exist (Hint: Cauchy).

Can you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Observe by the mean value theorem we have
\begin{align}
\left|f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-f\left(\frac{1}{m}\right)\right| = |f'(\xi)|\left|\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m}\right| \leq \frac{1}{2}\left|\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m}\right|
\end{align}
where $\xi \in [1/n, 1/m] \subset [0, 1]$.

Answer (score 0):

for every nonzero  $n$ and $p$ ,

$|a_{n+p}-a_n|\leq\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+p})\leq\frac{1}{2n}$

so $(a_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence.